# Error while creating a CSR

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, csr

During the creation of self-signed certificate using OpenSSL command line tool,  i'm encountered with an error

First I created a private key

`openssl genrsa -out MyKey1.key 2048`

While creating a CSR i'm getting an error

`openssl req -new -out MyCert1.req -key MyKey1.key -subj /CN=Description of the Server`

Error is

`problem creating object tsa-policy1=1.2.3.4.1`

`5364:error:08064066:object identifier routines:OBJ_create:pid exists:crypto\objects\obj_dat.c:689:`

Is there something i'm missing here ?

Comment: What version do you use? The error is interesting since it does not have much to do with ts module. Seems like it read the value from `openssl.cnf` but I don't see why. By the way, dont you miss quotation marks here: `-subj "/CN=Description of the Server"`?

Comment: The Version is 1.0.1 Lite. I did have the quotation, missed it while adding it here.

Answer (score 13):

1. Close the current cmd window and open new cmd window.
2. Continue  from the second "req" step.

Comment: worked for me. I think this is a big bug which should be solved by the developing team.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem while creating a self signed certificate...
setting these two environment variables fixed it!

```
set RANDFILE=c:\demo\.rnd
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg
```

I found the solution in [this blog post](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2015/03/30/howto-make-your-own-cert-with-openssl-on-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when creating client certificate request on Windows platform. Run application as Administrator solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I changed the administrator password while I was working so CMD lost the privileges. I closed the current CMD window and opened again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your attempted answer.  However, it should be noted that your answer is pretty much a duplicate of the top voted answer.  The *reason* why yours failed may be different (which could warrant a *comment* when you have enough rep), but the step you took to resolve it is exactly the same as noted in the top-voted-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the openssl.cnf file for this section:

```
# Policies used by the TSA examples.

tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7
```

Comment or remove the tsa_policyX lines, save the configuration file and launch the command again.